# Android Kotlin: check if view is not null before displaying Snackbar

Tags: android, kotlin

I used the following code to display a snackbar when data has been loaded using `retrofit`.

Sometimes, I get a `NullPointerException` when user tries to navigate from this fragment to another one whereas the request to get data is not yet terminated:

> kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>               at com.test.data.ui.cars.SiteCarsFragment$getCars$1.onFailure(SiteCarsFragment.kt:279)
>               at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$2.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:92)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

It's due to the fact that `view` is null in that case.

How can I modify the code to be sure that the view is defined before displaying the snackbar?

```
// Call getCars() API
val call = App.myService.getCars(site.id!!)
call.enqueue(object : Callback<CarsResponse> {

    override fun onResponse(call: Call<CarsResponse>, response: Response<CarsResponse>) {

        Log.i(tagLabel, "getCars() - onResponse() Result = ${response.body()}")

        if (response.code() == 200) {

            if (response.body()?.data?.size == 0){
                // do stuff
            } else {
                val sb = Snackbar.make(view!!, getString(R.string.mytitle), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                sb.view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.snackbarGreen))
                sb.show()
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<CarsResponse>, t: Throwable) {
        // do stuff
    }

})
```

Comment: can you show from where you calling this code?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, just edited my post

Comment: @wawanopoulos can you post the error stacktrace

Comment: Try putting in a try-catch block and create a Toast of that throwable. Paste the screenshot in post, let's see what's the error.

Comment: @wawanopoulos from where you are getting this view and add this view?.let{ ...your code goes here...}?: Log.e(TAG, "view is null") to save the crash because of view.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this one. I just added a null check

```
if(view != null){

  // Your code
  val sb = Snackbar.make(view!!, getString(R.string.mytitle), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
  sb.view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.snackbarGreen))
  sb.show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a view referenced to your activity (as activity views will not be destroyed if one of your fragment is). If you have any instance of activity's view, pass it there.

Or you can try this:

```
val sb = Snackbar.make(activity!!.findViewById(android.R.id.content), getString(R.string.mytitle), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

here I have used `!!` but activity will not be null unless its destroyed.

Edit: Here if you use view of fragment with null check, your snackbar will not be shown if your fragment's view is destroyed by switching between fragments. So you should use a activity's view or the code above if you want it to be shown even after your fragment's view destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to get rid of the double-bang(!!) operator and use the ***null-safety(?)*** operator, in the place where you are using **view!!** and **context!!.**

You should do something like this:

```
if(view !=null){
//TODO Snakbar code here.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: When you declare the snackbar (here 'sb') with 'view?' and when its null, the following two line can give an error.